# Octave error: can't read a variable in .m file

Tags: function, file-io, octave

I have a 'data' file, 'lab1.m' in my working directory.
Here the content of them.

data:

0 1 2 3 4

2 0 9 2 7

5 6 3 4 7

lab1.m:

```
load data
function y = RSSI_to_dBm(x, z)

    y = data(z, x);

end
```

However, there's an error when I call RSSI_to_dBm(2, 2):

octave:30> RSSI_to_dBm(2, 4)

error: `data' undefined near line 3 column 6

error: called from:

error:   RSSI_to_dBm at line 3, column 4

How can I solve it?
And how can I load 'data' to a variable name such as 'A'?
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried out a solution:

```
load data
function z = RSSI_to_dBm(x, y, data)

    z = data(x, y);

end
```

It works by passing the "data" to the function every time I call it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as well, but I would look into this:

"error: `data' undefined near line 3 column 6"

Because you only have 5 columns in your data array, but the error is referring to column 6.

Find column 6 and you may find your problem.  Make sure the dimensions of the data matrix match the dimensions that the "x" and "z" parameters take.  If they are askew, this can cause problems in MATLAB. I've found it easiest to monitor the dimensions of my matrices by using the debugger.

Hope that helps you in the right direction.

Comment: I think "column" means the column in my code, not the column in the matrix. And actually, my real data is a thousands * 16 matrix. Thank you for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data` is being interpreted as a variable name, but there is no variable called `data`.  The problem is easily solved by putting the file name in quotes:

```
load "data";
```

You might need to specify the file extension, and you can assign the result to a variable in the usual way:

```
A = load "data.txt";
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, however, there's a syntax error while I use 'A = load "data"'. And I'm sure that my original code did produce a variable called "data" by typing "whos".

Comment: And if I type "data(1,1)" on the octave command line, the result is "ans = 0".

Comment: What is the error message?  You might need to use the function syntax `A = load("data")`, but I can't really tell what your problem is without more information.  You're right that if you don't give any output arguments then `load` will automatically create a variable with the same name as the file and put the data in that.

Comment: "A = load("data")" works. But an error message shows up when trying to use A in a function (something like "Error: `A` undefined"). It, however, works if I pass A to the function every time I want to use it. So my solution is redefine RSSI_to_dBm(z,x) to RSSI_to_dBm(z,x,data)